# Question about "cosets" and subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a subgroup such that $|G| = 2|H|$.

Show that for any $a \in G$ that is not an element of $H$,

we have $a^2 \in H$ (Hint says that it suffices to show that $a^2H\ne aH$)

What I did is that since there are two left cosets,

G= $H\cup gH$,  for $g \in G$

since $a\not\in H$, $a\in gH$

so, $a=gh$ for $h \in H$

thus, $aH=gh^2$ and $a^2=ghgh$, thus $a^2(H)=ghgh^2$

So, they are not equal.

Anyone can suggest me what I did wrong and give me some clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

From $a = gh$, you cannot say $aH = gh^2$ since $aH$ is a set and $gh^2$ is an element of $G$. You can argue like this: If there exists an $a\in G\setminus H$ such that $a^2 H = aH$, then $a^2 h = ah'$ for some $h,h'\in H$. Thus $ah = h'$, or, $a = h'h^{-1}$. Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $h'h^{-1}\in H$, i.e., $a\in H$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry we havent yet covered normal group. Could you explain this by using concept of coset?

Comment: @nancy ok, I'll make changes.

Comment: @nancy I hope this edit helps.

Comment: Thank you! your edit really helped me!. But, one thing that I can not understand is that why it is sufficient to show that a^2H is not equal to aH when we want to show that a^2 is in H?

Comment: @nancy to have $a^2\in H$ means that $a^2 H = H$. But since $a\notin H$ by assumption, $aH \neq H$. So that's why it's sufficient to show $a^2 H \neq aH$.

Comment: @nancy to amplify: we just have 2 cosets, So if $a^2$ isn't in one, it must be in the other.